# Constant lock wait timeout

Tags: mysql, catalogsearch, fulltext

My site is constantly getting bogged down my lock wait timeouts. I'm using a virtual server with 6 cores and 6gb of ram. There's about 1,500 products on my site and it's a multi-domain installation. I'm also using the combined Like/Fulltext search. Any help would be greatly appreciated in what to do with this, as I've had 4 "mysql experts" look at it and they've done nothing. Here's an example from my var/reports folder:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:513:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `mg_catalogsearch_result` SELECT 8029 AS `query_id`, `s`.`product_id`, MATCH (s.data_index) AGAINST (:query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `relevance` FROM `mg_catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s`
 INNER JOIN `mg_catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = s.product_id WHERE (s.store_id = 4) AND (MATCH (s.data_index) AGAINST (:query IN BOOLEAN MODE)) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `relevance` = VALUES(`relevance`)";i:1;s:5011:"#0 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `mg...', Array)
#4 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `mg...', Array)
#5 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(393): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `mg...', Array)
#6 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Fulltext.php(136): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->prepareResult(Object(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext), 'liz', Object(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query))
#7 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Collection.php(55): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext->prepareResult()
#8 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/Ajaxcatalog/Model/Catalogsearch/Layer.php(15): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Collection->addSearchFilter('liz')
#9 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer.php(42): Smartwave_Ajaxcatalog_Model_Catalogsearch_Layer->prepareProductCollection(Object(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Collection))
#10 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php(101): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer->getProductCollection()
#11 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(91): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category->apply(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Category))
#12 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(73): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->_initFilter()
#13 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(117): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->init()
#14 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->_prepareLayout()
#15 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout))
#16 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalogsearch/l...', 'catalogsearch.l...')
#17 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('catalogsearch/l...', 'catalogsearch.l...')
#18 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(40): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#19 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#20 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#21 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#22 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#23 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks()
#24 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#25 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/Ajaxcatalog/controllers/CatalogSearch/ResultController.php(96): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#26 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Smartwave_Ajaxcatalog_CatalogSearch_ResultController->indexAction()
#27 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#28 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 /home/mysite/public_html/switchflats/index.php(183): Mage::run('lindsay*****...', 'website')
#32 {main}";s:3:"url";s:52:"/catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=129&color=301&q=liz";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:19:"lindsay*****_com";}
```

Comment: by any chance, is the reindexing process running when you get this error? specially the search index.

Comment: I don't believe so, but it is possible. I use the M2Epro Ebay/Amazon connection, so it's syncing/indexing inventory constantly throughout the day.

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing the timeout

```
[mysqld]
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=100
```

Restart mysql and try running that query again

```
INSERT INTO `mg_catalogsearch_result` SELECT 8029 AS `query_id`, `s`.`product_id`, MATCH (s.data_index) AGAINST (:query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `relevance` FROM `mg_catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s`
 INNER JOIN `mg_catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = s.product_id WHERE (s.store_id = 4) AND (MATCH (s.data_index) AGAINST (:query IN BOOLEAN MODE)) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `relevance` = VALUES(`relevance`)";
```

You may need a higher timeout, if this fails you might need to look at your mysql config